# In place list sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have a list of objects (L1) and another list of integers (L2) that represents the order that the objects should be in.  For reasons that aren't important to this problem, the only operation that I'm allowed to perform on L1 is

```
L1.move(int fromIndex, int toIndex)
```

I was wondering if someone could point me to an algorithm that can put the objects in L1 in the order specified by L2 using only this one operation, or an in place sort.

Thanks

Comment: Is the problem finding any algorithm that does that in the first place, or finding one that's efficient as well?

Comment: There are no more than 20 elements in the list, so I'm not really concerned about speed.

Comment: The item is inserted before N, if I have a list of objects a, b, c in L1 and I call L1.move(2, 0) the new list is c, a, b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at these:
Bubble sort, Comb sort, Selection sort, Insertion sort, Heapsort, Shell sort.

Comment: Yay! Comb sort! (Hardly anyone uses it, which is a shame :-/) Also, the list is reduces slightly is a stable sort is required...

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950451/c-given-a-desired-order-need-a-space-efficient-list-reordering-or-sorting), I've posted an answer about a way to rearrange an array using O(1) additional space.  I'm not sure it will exactly match the semantics of `move` you have, but it might be applicable.